# Focus element on the iPhone browser without showing keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, barcode, usability

We're building a web page on which users will have to enter barcodes. It has to work fine on the mobile device (iPhone in our case) browser (Safari/Chrome, doesn't matter). We've got a barcode scanner case for iPhone which is supposed to simplify the process. So when the page is opened we already set focus to the barcode box (which is input[type='password']). We face following issues:

1) Input element if not focused by default. It gets focus only when user touches the screen.

2) (which is more important) When input element is focused keyboard pops up always. We don't want it because we have barcode scanner. Keyboard is not necessary at all.

Is there any way to overcome these problems?